# Cyberpanel openlitespeed Wordpress site down every second day

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I have hosted my WordPress website on a digital ocean cyberpanel droplet, i don't know what is the problem every second day my webiste gets down i have to reboot the server to restart the site.

Also there are STDERR in the logs when i checked the logs

Here is the some of the logs

```
WordPress database error Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_38d_0.MAI' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device") for query SELECT  t.*, tt.* FROM wpfv_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wpfv_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN wpfv_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tr.object_id IN (5470) ORDER BY t.name ASC  made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/xyz/page.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/xyz/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPSEO_Frontend->head, do_action('wpseo_head'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPSEO_OpenGraph->opengraph, do_action('wpseo_opengraph'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPSEO_OpenGraph->tags, get_the_tags, get_the_terms, wp_get_object_terms, get_terms, WP_Term_Query->query, WP_Term_Query->get_terms

WordPress database error Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_38d_0.MAI' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device") for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wpfv_options` made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wp_cron, spawn_cron, set_transient, update_option
```

The error logs is related to the wordpress database as i don't know why my cpanel is not working properly.

If anyone knows the issue please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It seems like /tmp require sufficient permission. Check the directory permissions of your wp-content folder. That directory needs to have 755 permissions.

Comment: @Karthick as i have check on my server 
here is the permission to the drwxr-xr-x  6   4096 Apr  5 09:47 wp-content

Comment: try to set the permission using below command to wp-content and all sub-directories, if it doesn't work, change the permission to 775 & give a try.

chmod -R 755 wp-content